# Eclipse db2 xml column return value is a object address

Tags: eclipse, db2

I use Eclipse(Oxygen.2) in the Company.

In my database i have a column and it's typ **XML**.

If I make a `SELECT` query my return value is object address `com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.re@23717212` but I want to have xml index.

What i did :

1. Open the Eclipse
2. File-> New Database Connection
3. Write the Query : Select * from benutzer;
4. In the message column i have object-ID(com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.re@23717212).
   What i need is the index from XML not object-ID.

[image]

Comment: Edit your question to show your SQL , and your Db2-server operating-system (z/os, i-series, linux/unix/windows).

Comment: show your code & also if you are using jdbc to run select query or something else?

Comment: What I have only a Database. I didn't wrote Java Code. I made only a connection to Database. My Query : SELECT * FROM BENUTZER; The Message Column has the type xml. This column returns me com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.re@23717212.

Comment: @Z.B
Use xmlserialize(message as varchar(4000)) to get a string representation of an xml value in your SELECT statement.

Comment: I tried it. Eclipse give a sql qery error. "Query execution failed"

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the result set grid in Ecliplse does not know how to render the XML data type and simply uses the `toString()` method. Let Db2 do the job and, as [Mark Barinstein](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10418264/mark-barinstein) suggested in comments, use the [`XMLSERIALIZE()`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0022194.html) function to convert XML to a string:

```
SELECT XMLSERIALIZE(message as VARCHAR(4000)), -- your other columns
FROM BENUTZER
```

Adjust the target VARCHAR length as necessary.

Comment: Eclipse returned me "Error executing query" Query execution faild. SQL Error [42884]: No authorized routine named "XMLSERIALIZE" of type "FUNCTION" having compatible arguments was found.. SQLCODE=-440, SQLSTATE=42884, DRIVER=3.67.27
  No authorized routine named "XMLSERIALIZE" of type "FUNCTION" having compatible arguments was found.. SQLCODE=-440, SQLSTATE=42884, DRIVER=3.67.27

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the libraries.

I had two libraries : db2jcc.jar and db2jcc4.jar.

The firstone (db2jcc.jar) has blocked the secondone (db2jcc4.jar).
If I remove the first driver then i can see the xml index.
If I change the sequence i can also see the index form xml file.

That was what i need.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

cast to char to view the xml.

```
select xmlserialize(myxmlcolumn)  as myxml from mytable
```

Comment: You get the following trying to do this: `SQL0461N  A value with data type "SYSIBM.XML" cannot be CAST to type "SYSIBM.CHARACTER"`

Comment: I am sure it isn't the name, It works on a another computer but not on my. She have no idea what she did. Mybe it is a eclipse configuration, a plugin or a library .

Comment: @danny117 Still doesn't work. You can't omit the data type definition. Check the link to the xmlserialize function definition above.